# Do I have to publish my project in order for it to work with any enterprise (Google Apps for work) accounts?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am implementing an integration with Google Drive, which is to show a user's  Drive files on our own website (after a 3-legged OAuth2 authorization).

So it is not a webapp that you will connect to the Google Drive UI, and thus I don't see the need to publish it in Apps Marketplace.

My project is created with my personal (free) account on console.developers.google.com, 
and I'd like to confirm here: if not published, will it still work with any types of accounts, especially with enterprise accounts(e.g. Google Apps for Work)?

Comment: not clear what you wrote. a website? how is it called?

Comment: It is an enterprise website. We want to show the user's Drive files on our website's page, so that a group of users can collaborate over their shared Drive files, without switching to Google, while they can utilize other features of our website.

Answer (score 1):

It does not need to be published as long as the domain administrator has not disabled Drive Apps. If a domain admin has disabled Drive Apps, I believe publishing to the Google Apps Marketplace is required so that the domain admin can install the App for all domain users.